# query for oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to query the below conditions:
Whenever “Approval Date” will be “NULL” , the SLA calculation will be remain same.
However whenever “NOT NULL” means hold value then in that case , 
SLA calculation will be as per below

```
If  (Actual.finish  < (ADJUSTEDTARGETRESOLUTIONTIME + approval date) ) then “MET”
else “NOTMET”
```

had developed this query: `CASE WHEN TICKET.STATUS IN ('APPROVED_DATE' + 'ADJUSTEDTARGETRESOLUTIONTIME') >= ACTUALFINISH THEN 'MET' ELSE 'NOTMET'`
but it is throwing error:  faultString = "ORA-00905: missing keyword

please help to fix this query

```
CASE WHEN TICKET.STATUS IN ('APPROVED_DATE' + 'ADJUSTEDTARGETRESOLUTIONTIME') >= ACTUALFINISH THEN 'MET' ELSE 'NOTMET'
```

Answer (score 2):

- Removed the apostrophe's around your column names.. that makes them strings and not column names whose value is derived on a row by row basis.
- What is the point of the `in` statement and ticket.status? it's not in your if so I eliminated it.
- added keyword 'END' to case statements. (invalid syntax otherwise)

.

```
CASE WHEN APPROVED_DATE + ADJUSTEDTARGETRESOLUTIONTIME >= ACTUALFINISH 
     THEN 'MET' 
     ELSE 'NOTMET' 
 END
```

Concerns: what are the data types for the 3 fields in question?  All date/time?

Comment: THESE ARE ALL DATE/TIME.

Comment: WHEN TRYING TO RUN THE ABOVE QUERY ITS SHOWING ERROR:  faultString = "ORA-00975: date + date not allowed

Comment: Can you provide an example values for each.  I was expecting something like `'20190101' (date) + 2 (Days) >= '20190105' (Date)`  when adding in oracle unless we specify the interval, days is expected.